# Login Session Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, session, authentication, cloudflare

Does anyone experience the same thing like me?

In Wordpress, 
After I login at homepage, it seem fine. But it show that I m not login when I navigate to single page. I am using Cloudflare, Theme My Login Plugin.

Any there any way to debug and find out what happening for this?

Comment: please add your site link..

Comment: this working very well i am not login your site but display home page.

Comment: @ravipatel Sorry if I confuse u. Here the scenario, User register and login to the wordpress as subscriber. The navigation bar should display as member. When user login in home page, it does display member but it show the user haven login when it navigate to another page.

Comment: i confuse... you can remove navigation bar after login as subscriber.

Comment: @ravipatel If i removed the sticky navigation bar, how should my subscriber logout??

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something to [restore original visitor IP](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200038166-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-my-server-logs-) using CloudFLare?

Since we are a reverse proxy for sites, our IPs are going to show until you install something to restore visitor IP. My thinking here is that it may be affecting something with sessionsthat limits logins by IP or something (also a highly recommended step).

Comment: izzit?? So is there any reference reading I can go to? Not really know what should I do from here.